# Hibernate: null index column for collection in one-to-many relation

Tags: hibernate, list, indexing, one-to-many

I'm trying to map a one-to-many / many-to-one relationship in Hibernate with a List of child entities. Doing the same with a Set on other relations works find, but I need to have a List with order of child-entities.

What I've done so far is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class Event {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
    private List<Message> messages; //Message entitiy is the child
//getters+setters+and some other stuff like id
}
```

And here's the ManyToOne side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="eventid")
    private Event event;
//getters+setters+and some other stuff like id
}
```

On this I can insert a Message, it will be added to the database (postgres). But problem is on getting the messages as a List: I get 2 results of the same Message when only one was added and is visible on the database!

Of course, I've done some research and found that an index is needed on a List. But nothing I've tried, worked out. All I got is an exception of: "null index column for collection...". None of the solutions I've found on here and via google seemed to work and there are so many "solutions" that I don't really know which of those are even supposed to work!

Does anyone have an idea on how to realize this relation? I'd be greatfull for any advice!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem when also using @OrderColumn as mentioned by @dan-torrey and @peter-wippermann, however in my case the problem was really trivial. When connecting the entities, I forgot one side. Eg. in the above case, I've only done *message.setEvent(event)* but not *event.getMessages().add(message)*. Due to how Hibernate works, this gets persisted into the database without a warning, it only started to fail when I've added the @OrderColumn later.

I know that the original problem does not include @OrderColumn, however the above error message should appear only when Hibernate is actually using an index column.. (maybe the OP had this configured in some other way..)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with an old version of hibernate (3.5.6) and find one good non-invasive workaround: try to change your `List<Message>` to `Set<Message>` Object and use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I ran into this problem today.

I resolved it by adding these annotations on the setter method for the parent of the list:

```
@OneToMany()
@OrderColumn( name = "LIST_ORDER" )
@Cascade( { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE } )
@ForeignKey( name = "FK_..." )
```

I was receiving the exception, because I had a "mappedBy" attribute in my OneToMany annotation.

Perhaps this will help if you have not already solved this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem and also used '@OrderColumn' like you. However, the thread opener didn't.
What I can agree to is, if you have an @OrderColumn, double check that it's not null. In my case the database was prefilled with values that included null values for that ordering column *doh*